# How do I expand a range of numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, range

Lets say I have this range of numbers, I want to expand these intervals. What is going wrong with my code here? The answer I am getting isn't correct :(

intervals are only represented with -
each 'thing' is separated by ;

I would like the output to be:
-6 -3 -2 -1 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 14 15 17 18 19 20

```
range_expansion('-6;-3--1;3-5;7-11;14;15;17-20 ')

function L=range_expansion(S)
% Range expansion
if nargin < 1; 
    S='[]';
end

if all(isnumeric(S) | (S=='-')  | (S==',') | isspace(S))
    error 'invalid input';
end
ixr = find(isnumeric(S(1:end-1)) & S(2:end) == '-')+1;
S(ixr)=':';
S=['[',S,']'];
L=eval(S) ;

end


ans =

    -6    -2    -2    -4    14    15    -3
```

Comment: @LuisMendo no if you need more information please don't hesitate to ask but I have had a lot of people in the past just leaving horrible comments and not asking for anymore additional information that I may have forgotten

Comment: @LuisMendo Please see my edited post and see what you think

Comment: Better, but you don't indicate what the desired output is

Comment: It looks like `in = '-6,-3--1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20 '; out = str2num(regexprep(in, '(?<=\d)-',':'))` could do what you want. But you need to clarify if the format is always going to be like that in your example: will numbers always be integers? Is there any possibility that the string contains letters etc?

Comment: @LuisMendo The numbers will always be integers. The format will be seperated by ';' instead of ',' Intervals are only ever represented with '-' How do I alter your code so that it understands each number or intervals are separated by semi-colons and not commas?

Comment: See my answer. Please edit that information into your question (that is, edit the example input with the actual format using `;`), so that my answer matches the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`regexprep`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to replace `;`by `,` and the `-` that define ranges by `:`. Those `-` are identified by them being preceded by a digit. The result is a string that can be transformed into the desired output using [`str2num`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html). However, since this function evaluates the string, for safety it is first checked that the string only contains the allowed characters:

```
in = '-6;-3--1;3-5;7-11;14;15;17-20 '; % example
assert(all(ismember(in, '0123456789 ,;-')), 'Characters not allowed') % safety check
out = str2num(regexprep(in, {'(?<=\d)-' ';'}, {':' ','})); % replace and evaluate
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have updated the question too. This code doesn't seem to work. The output seems to be blank, nothing is returned. But the one in your other comment worked correctly

Comment: @Boo So is your separator `,`or `;`? I'm confused. My code works with your example; see [here](https://tio.run/##HY7LDoIwEEX3fsVszLQJk1gQUCtx4W@4qTAqkVfaohjit2Pj7uYk9@T0pTcvXpa6gwKQMk0JkdIJpTonpbTaapVqlVO8AdSwBp5MOzS8Ms6x9cI0jahdy@2Vrai7CHCj4mSbZvluD5EmlDKw88NYU3q2DrreQzj1b65QBp8zN/YfKB9cPlf96EOG8zbuxlZYvvM0WB7@4hnF6VhcKkkYSvAbzXgIK8KvlMvyAw)

Comment: ah no your second code has made it into a variable. The first code just put the output in the command window